# REST API for Azure SQL DB on Linux Machine

Tags: python, linux, rest, azure, azure-sql-database

Question. I would like to create a **REST API** for the data stored in an **Azure SQL DB** that will allow me to do GET and POST operation using **Python**. Currently I managed to print the results of my query on the terminal but how do I convert it to **JSON** format and allow it to run 24/7 on **linux** (perhaps change port?)? Below is my script:

```
import pyodbc
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Energy(Resource):
    def get(self):
        server = 'testserver.database.windows.net'
        database = 'testdb'
        username = 'admin'
        password = '735t'
        driver= '{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}'
        connexion = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';PORT=1433;SERVER='+server+';PORT=1443;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
        cursor = connexion.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT TOP (100) * FROM [dbo].[Power_Meter]")
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        while row:
           GeneratedCode = str(row[0])
           ReportedDate = str(row[1])
           print (str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]))
           row = cursor.fetchone()

        rest_row = jsonify(row)
        return rest_row

api.add_resource(Energy, '/DPM')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and this is the output result on localhost:5000/DPM

```
null
```

Can anyone suggest me how to go about solving this issue? Thanks

Comment: `app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)` could you modify your port.

Comment: If you want to execute it 24/7 on linux. You could execute it as a background tasks.  Using `nohup python <file> &`

Comment: You could save your script as a python file. For example, sql.py. When you execute `python sql.py >>test.log`. The log will save into test.log. You could parse data to json format.

Comment: Yes, you could modify port to 80.

Comment: I suggest you could save output to a file.

Comment: Hi @Shengbao Shui. Thanks for the prompt reply.
**app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000) could you modify your port**
_Oh yeah. Thanks for the solution. So I just have to allocate the right port to replace port 80 right?_
 
**If you want to execute it 24/7 on linux. You could execute it as a background tasks. Using nohup python <file> &** 
_Thank you. Yes. It works_

Comment: **You could save your script as a python file. For example, sql.py. When you execute python sql.py >>test.log. The log will save into test.log. You could parse data to json format.**
_Are you suggesting that I can't use jsonify or flask or json to parse the string to JSON format? So I need to parse the test.log instead?. It would be nice if I could just parse the results into structured JSON format_

Comment: Yes, it depends on your need. You also could parse data to json firstly.

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT. Apologies for the late response. I was looking for a much faster option that is to parse the results straightaway without having to save the output to a file then parse it at the end of the process. If you think this is the best option, could you care to share me the method to parse the file into JSON then expose it to the localhost:5000/DPM?

Comment: @ShengbaoShui-MSFT. Pardon me. I'm actually quite new to python. So I am now looking at options on how to move the results in terminal to a file then convert it to JSON

Comment: Sorry I am not good at this, maybe you could ask a new question about this. Your original data and json format you want. Maybe you could ask on json tag.

Comment: You could use `nohup python sql.py &`. It will let your script run 7*24. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @ShengbaoShui-MSFT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run your script 24/7 on Linux, you could execute it as a background task. Using `nohup python sql.py>> test.log &`

```
man nohup

nohup - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty

& to the command line to run in the background:
```

If you want to change port, just change like below:

```
app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000)
```

I suggest you could store output to a file. Then you could parse  data to json format.